# ListView color items at runtime

Tags: delphi, listview

I know that i can set custom colors to items when i add them to the list using OnDraw Events but i want to change colors of the items at a certain point after they are already in the list.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: I don't understand. You say you can draw in a specific color in `OnDraw`. If so, then what is the problem?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If I repaint the listview it has an annoying flicker so I was wondering if there is another method in achieving such functionality.

Comment: Why are you calling `Repaint`? Anyway, it seems to me that you have asked an XY question. What you really want to do is avoid the flicker.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan let's say i have a item that is colored in green after a certain amount of time i want to paint that in red . What should i use if I don't use Repaint ?

Comment: Use [`UpdateItems`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomListView.UpdateItems). You just specify the range of your single item.

Comment: @opc0de What TLama said!

Comment: You can vote for closing. I didn't worked much with listviews sorry

Comment: @TLama you could write an answer if others encounter this problem in the future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To redraw only certain items use the [`UpdateItems`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomListView.UpdateItems) method. It has two input parameters where you can specify the range of the items to be redrawn. If you are going to redraw only one item, then just specify that one item index as a range.

In this example I'm storing the color of the item into the [`TListItem.Data`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListItem.Data) property and fading this color in the timer's event. After changing the value I call the [`UpdateItems`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomListView.UpdateItems) function which force the draw item event to fire. And yes, without [`DoubleBuffered`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListView.DoubleBuffered) set, it flickers (even when you set the timer's interval e.g. to 500ms).

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListView1.AddItem('Item 1', TObject(clWhite));
  ListView1.AddItem('Item 2', TObject(clWhite));
  ListView1.AddItem('Item 3', TObject(clWhite));
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  ListView1.Canvas.Brush.Color := TColor(Item.Data);
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  C: Byte;
  I: TColor;

  procedure ChangeItemColor;
  begin
    I := TColor(ListView1.Items[0].Data);
    C := GetRValue(I);
    if C < 150 then C := 255 else Dec(C);
    I := RGB(C, C, C);
    ListView1.Items[0].Data := TObject(I);
  end;

begin
  // color change
  ChangeItemColor;
  // repaint of the item with index 1
  ListView1.UpdateItems(1, 1);
end;
```

Comment: Any help as to what the c++ equivalent of this would look like?