# FireMonkey TListView: How to color items at runtime?

Tags: android, delphi, listview, firemonkey

It is possible to use custom drawing for the VCL TListView, which allows you to colour individual items ([here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430797/listview-color-items-at-runtime) using the rather dodgy approach of putting a `TColor` in the `Data` of an item.)

However, in the XE7 FMX version of the `TListVew` control, there is no `OnCustomDraw` event. I tried some options, but nothing seems to change the colors. How do I do this?

Comment: You aren't reopening anything. You are asking a new question on a new topic. This new question is about FMX.

Comment: The old question is about VCL and Windows. Your new question is about a totally different UI framework (FMX) and a totally different OS (Android).

Comment: Edited - you are asking about the FMX control. FMX works quite differently to the VCL and it's not that the event has gone, but that it doesn't (and hasn't ever) existed. Instead you need a different approach. Rewrote to indicate this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the color of each list item's text using the `TListViewItem.Objects.DetailObject.TextColor` property. But there is no native property for changing each list item's background color.

Accordingly to [TListView Items background color](http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.firemonkey/tlistview-items-background-colo/1060231):

> How to change the background color of TListView Items?
>   ...
>   You have to use a style. So add a stylebook en either use one of the 
>   styles that come with Delphi or right click the listview "edit custom 
>   style"to make the style. dubbleclick on the stylebook to open the style 
>   and modify the listviewstyle.

But that does not explain how to apply a different style to each list item.

Answer (score 3):

Each item has an OnPaint event. Assign an event handler like the following.

```
procedure TfrmModelArchiver.lst1Paint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas;
  const ARect: TRectF);
begin
    Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Red;
    Canvas.FillRect(ARect, 0, 0, AllCorners, 0.2);
end;
```

In this event handler, the opacity is set to 0.2 so the text can show through. If you set the opacity to 1, you will need to write the text as well as draw the background as shown below.

```
procedure TfrmModelArchiver.lst1Paint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas;
  const ARect: TRectF);
begin
    Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Red;
    Canvas.FillRect(ARect, 0, 0, AllCorners, 1);
    Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Black;
    Canvas.FillText(ARect, 'some text', False, 1, [],
      TTextAlign.taLeading);
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.fmxexpress.com/very-customizable-listview-control-for-firemonkey-in-delphi-10-berlin-on-android-and-ios/) is solution.

This modern ListView component is available for Delphi 10 Berlin with FireMonkey on Android, IOS, OSX, and Windows. One nice feature is that it has both horizontal and vertical mode.
SetColorItemSelected, SetColorItemFill, SetColorBackground, SetColorItemSeparator, SetColorText, SetColorTextSelected, SetColorTextDetail, SetColorHeader, SetColorTextHeader, and many other properties.

Comment: can you explain more the solution? the link can disapear some day

Comment: This is a custom unit FMX.ListView.pas and FMX.ListView.Types.pas. You can test demo here https://github.com/rzaripov1990/ModernListView